# How to aggregate groups of only more than 1 in a pandas pivot table

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table

I have the following code but I only want to aggregate on groups of two or more:

```
 pivot = pd.pivot_table(pct, values = ['CERT'], index= 'ST', aggfunc={'CERT': [min, max, np.mean]}).reset_index(level = 0).set_index('ST', drop = False)
```

Tried Grouper but realized later that this only worked for time series.

```
 Sample Data Input:

 ST  CERT
 AL  8909
 TX  9805
 TX  7890

 Sample Data Output:

 ST  Min_Cert Max_Cert Mean_Cert
 TX  7890     9805     X
```

As can be seen above only TX data is aggregated as it has more than two entries.

Comment: Would you like pose some sample data and your expected out put ?

Comment: @Wen I have added data above

Answer (score 1):

Why not just filter first all rows that have `count` 1?

```
c = df.groupby('ST').count()>1
new_df = df[df.ST.isin(c[c.values].index)]
```

Then just use your working code

```
pd.pivot_table(new_df, values = ['CERT'], index= 'ST', aggfunc={'CERT': [min, max, np.mean]}).reset_index(level = 0).set_index('ST', drop = False)
```

Answer (score 0):

@RafaelC Thanks for your solution. I also found this other solution if we still wanted to use a pivot_table method. Thanks.

```
pivot = pd.pivot_table(pct.loc[pct.groupby('ST').CERT.transform('count')>1], values=
['CERT'], index=['ST'], aggfunc={'CERT': [min, max, np.mean]}).reset_index(level = 
0).set_index('ST', drop = False)

pivot.columns = ['ST', 'Min_CERT', 'Max_CERT', 'Mean_CERT']
```

Thanks for your help.